# Integral with negative radicand $ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-a^2-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

I saw this integral:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-a^2-x^2}}.
$$
I tried to solve it by taking $-1$ as common factor which leaded me to:
$\frac{1}{i\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$ which leads to:
$-i\ln(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x)$

However I placed it on Wolfram Alpha and it says the result is:
$$
\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-a^2-x^2}}\right)
$$
So my question would be..is it possible that both expressions are equivalent??? Sorry if this a dumb question....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $i =\sqrt{-1}$.  If you want to factor it out, it is $i$, not $-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\arctan (i z) = i \text{arctanh(}z) =i \ln \sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$.
Thus

$$
\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-a^2-x^2}}\right)
=\arctan\left(-i \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\right)\\
= -i \ln \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-x}}
= -i \ln {\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+x}{a^2}}\\
\hspace{-4cm}=-i\ln(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x)+C$$

Comment: Thanks. You guys rock.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arctan\dfrac x{\sqrt{-a^2-x^2}}=y$

$$\tan^2y=-\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+a^2}$$

$$-\cot^2y=1+\dfrac{a^2}{x^2}$$

$x=ai\sin y$ where $i^2=-1$

$$f(x)=x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}=a(\cos y+i\sin y)=ae^{iy}$$ assuming $a\cos y\ge0$

$$\ln(f(x))=\ln a+i(y+2n\pi)$$